# conditional statement that checks current url root directory (/en/ or /cn/ languages in this case)

Tags: magento, url, root, conditional-statements, php

My Magento website is bilingual (English default and Chinese), and has the Zopim livechat. Apparently, Zopim has language detection, but it didn't work for our website... I had a colleage use a Chinese computer with a Chinese IP and a Chinese browser visit the Chinese side of our website, and the Zopim live chat was STILL in English. So wtf?

I contacted the Zopim support team and they gave me some code to "put on all the Chinese pages." However, that's not how my website actually operates. I have a language plug-in/extension that translates certain words on the default-English webpages by replacing those words with their Chinese counterparts in .CSV translation docs on the server, but the phtml pages themselves are not technically Chinese. They are still the default pages which run the translation function, when the root is /ch/ instead of /en/

I thought maybe just putting it on the header.phtml block or the footer.phtml block might work, but actually those blocks are also just default blocks with the root-check-launches-translate feature built into it.

This is the code the Zopim support rep gave me:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$zopim(function(){
$zopim.livechat.setLanguage('en');
$zopim.livechat.bubble.setText('Click here for livechat!’);
$zopim.livechat.badge.setText('test');
$zopim.livechat.window.setTitle('Zopim Chat Support');
$zopim.livechat.concierge.setTitle('Zopim Chat Support');
$zopim.livechat.setGreetings({
'online': ['online short message', 'online long message'],
'offline': ['offline short message', 'offline long message']
});
});
</script>
```

So, can a simple conditional [IF] statement be added to the top of this that can check if the root is /ch/... [THEN] apply all the following code? Also, am I allowed to put that on the footer or header (which appear on all pages), or do I have to do add it to index.html (which for some reason I can't even find in the server)?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this piece of code in the file (footer.phtml) of your current theme:

```
<?php if (strpos(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode(), 'zh_') !== false): ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $zopim(function(){
    $zopim.livechat.setLanguage('en');
    $zopim.livechat.bubble.setText('Click here for livechat!’);
    $zopim.livechat.badge.setText('test');
    $zopim.livechat.window.setTitle('Zopim Chat Support');
    $zopim.livechat.concierge.setTitle('Zopim Chat Support');
    $zopim.livechat.setGreetings({
    'online': ['online short message', 'online long message'],
    'offline': ['offline short message', 'offline long message']
    });
    });
    </script>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the quick reply!!! It didn't work as I flipped back & forth from English side of the site to the Chinese side... & I tried different variations of the 'zh_' (cn_, cn, zh, zh_CN) as well as different variations of 'en' as well. But all that may be useless because I'm at home on an English language OS & an English language browser. Meaning that perhaps your suggestion to use "getLocalCode' is specifically for computer language and/or browser language. If that is the case, then  I will have to wait until tomorrow to test it on one of the Chinese computers at the office.

Comment: At the office now... didn't work. Tried with zh_ and zh_CN at the top.... Am I doing something wrong?